# SQL Server 2008 changed table name bizarre behavior

Tags: sql-server

I changed the name of one of my tables, then afterwards encoded some data then pulled it using a view to my surprise the data is not showing. I tried renaming it back to its original name with no luck the same thing is happening.

Then finally I tried retyping the data on one of the columns and then executed the view and there the data is finally showing now the problem arises I need to re encode the data on one of the column every time a data is inserted which is obviously not a good thing to do.

here is the code on how i added some data

```
tblcsv.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[7] { new DataColumn("unit_name", typeof(string)), new DataColumn("unit", typeof(string)), new DataColumn("adrress", typeof(string)), new DataColumn("latitude", typeof(string))
                ,new DataColumn("longitude" , typeof(string)) , new DataColumn("region" , typeof(string)) , new DataColumn("linkid" , typeof(string))});
                string ReadCSV = File.ReadAllText(forex);
                foreach (string csvRow in ReadCSV.Split('\n'))
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(csvRow))
                    {
                        //Adding each row into datatable  
                        tblcsv.Rows.Add();
                        int count = 0;
                        foreach (string FileRec in csvRow.Split(','))
                        {
                            tblcsv.Rows[tblcsv.Rows.Count - 1][count] = FileRec;
                            if (count == 5)
                            {
                                tblcsv.Rows[tblcsv.Rows.Count - 1][6] = link;
                            }
                            count++;
                        }
                    }


                }


                    string consString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["diposlConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
                    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(consString))
                    {
                        using (SqlBulkCopy sqlBulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(con))
                        {
                            //Set the database table name
                            sqlBulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "dbo.FRIENDLY_FORCES";

                            //[OPTIONAL]: Map the Excel columns with that of the database table
                            sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("unit_name", "unit_name");
                            sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("unit", "unit");
                            sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("adrress", "adrress");
                            sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("latitude", "latitude");
                            sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("longitude", "longitude");
                            sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("region", "region");
                            sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("linkid", "linkid");
                            con.Open();
                            sqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(tblcsv);
                            con.Close();
                        }
                    }
```

the column region is where i manually edited the data

Did the renaming of the table did something to my data?

Or am I just missing something?

Thank you

Comment: any chance you can provide a script to reproduce the problem ?

Comment: if you renamed the table, but haven't modified the view to refer to the new table name, the view will stop working ([see MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337520.aspx)).  What happens if you `select * from yourTable`?

Comment: of course i have modified the view like i said at my explanation that i edited one of the column then the data started showing up